# Android Undefined getActivity error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

i am following a tutorial to develop android chat app but getting error(red line) in

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

these two and my sdk version is 23, i'm new to android. i don't know what to do ??? plz help me out.

```
package learn2crack.chat;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
SharedPreferences prefs;
EditText name, mobno;
Button login;
List<NameValuePair> params;
ProgressDialog progress;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Chat", 0);

    name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    mobno = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.mobno);
    login = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.log_btn);
    progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progress.setMessage("Registering ...");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);



    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progress.show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString("REG_FROM", mobno.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("FROM_NAME", name.getText().toString());
            edit.commit();
            new Login().execute();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser json = new JSONParser();
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobno", mobno.getText().toString()));
        params.add((new BasicNameValuePair("reg_id",prefs.getString("REG_ID",""))));

        JSONObject jObj = json.getJSONFromUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/login",params);
        return jObj;



    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        progress.dismiss();
        try {
            String res = json.getString("response");
            if(res.equals("Sucessfully Registered")) {
                Fragment reg = new UserFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, reg);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),res,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which is the getActivity() that is giving you an error?

Comment: first 
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
these two are in red then
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Chat", 0);
in this getActivity() is in red

Comment: Do you allready have those imports :S

Comment: see i am follow a tutorial for developing chat app and they import these two thats why

Comment: Error:(18, 36) error: cannot find symbol class Fragment
Error:(27, 17) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(32, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(24, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(75, 21) error: cannot find symbol class Fragment
Error:(76, 21) error: cannot find symbol class FragmentTransaction
Error:(76, 46) error: cannot find symbol method getFragmentManager()
Error:(78, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable FragmentTransaction
Error:(82, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

Comment: ok i removed those two then it giving me errors which i mentioned above

Comment: I've copy this class on my sample project and it doesn't give this error, try to clean your project or rebuild it again

Comment: Do you have an Activity or FragmentActivity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95106/discussion-between-mayur-raikwar-and-skizo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what's already posted, you need to use the `SupportFragmentManager` instead of `FragmentManager`.

```
import android.support.v4.app.SupportFragmentManager;
```

Change this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

to this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Will he need to call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`?

Comment: If you put this on your answer it will be an upvote for you :)

Comment: @Skizo is it necessary to extend FragmentActivity in this case ?

Comment: Yes, he will only could call getSupportFragmentManager if he has a FragmentActivity

Comment: Error:(42, 38) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(49, 38) error: cannot find symbol method getFragmentManager()
Error:(108, 38) error: cannot find symbol method
getFragmentManager()
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
now i am getting these four errors

Comment: @Skizo or he could extend AppCompatActivity in case he was using the support library. Worked for me.

Comment: @MayurRaikwar use getSupportFragmentManager instead.

Comment: We need to continue this discussion in chat. I'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: tell me your fb id ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94972/discussion-between-jdev-and-mayur-raikwar).

Answer (score 3):

You are importing wrong the `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction`, replace your imports :

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

To `v4Library` :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: getActivity() and this.getActivity() are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import these

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need context in order to get shared preferences, to do that you can use context provided with `ViewGroup container`

```
prefs = container.getContext().getSharedPreferences("Chat", 0);
```

Comment: thanks but now it giving me Error:(41, 38) error: cannot find symbol method getFragmentManager()

Comment: Try getSupportFragmentManager()